# How does specific apps find "hidden" Bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth

Segway has made an electric scooter. It has Bluetooth so I can connect my phone to it. When I open the app, it asks me if I want to scan for devices. I hit yes and my scooter comes up. I can then see statistics and so on from the device.

If I open up Bluetooth settings on any other device, I cannot find the scooter. I know the scooter comes with a specific name (like Ninebot1234), but I can change that name.

I basically want to connect any other device to that scooter, then perhaps try and send some Bluetooth commands to get those statistics.

I want to research more into connecting to a hidden Bluetooth device, so I don't have to specify the Bluetooth address, but I'm not really sure how I should approach that. What kind of technology or software lies underneath making a hidden Bluetooth "network", and how does the app know which Bluetooth devices to scan for?

Comment: There are few ways how app works: 1. Your scooter can be BLE device; 2. Scoote'rs app knows it MAC (may be it has list of MACs); 3. Scooter connects to app instead of app connects to scooter.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko 1. Could be! 2. That's what I'm thinking could be true as well. 3. Doubt it. Is there any way I can find BLE devices using my Android phone, for example? Without knowing their name of anything.

Comment: Ah, I found an app called "BLE Scanner". I found it and I can read some of the services. Awesome. I'll look further into how I can read the data properly now! Thanks